# Conversion from `const char[]` to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, string, constructor, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to make a class that wraps a pointer around another type. With all of the extraneous bits removed, it looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class field {
    std::unique_ptr<T> t_;

public:
    field() : t_(nullptr) {}

    field(const T &t) : t_(std::make_unique<T>(t)) {}

    field<T> &operator=(const T &t) {
        t_.reset(new T(t));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I can declare them by explicitly calling their constructors, but not with `=`, like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    field<std::string> strA("Hello");
    field<std::string> strB = "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
-snip-/StringImplicit/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
-snip-/StringImplicit/main.cpp:21:31: error: conversion from ‘const char [6]’ to non-scalar type ‘field<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ requested
   21 |     field<std::string> strB = "Hello";
      |                               ^~~~~~~
```

Where am I going wrong? I can't seem to use `field<std::string>`s in class constructors with raw strings without this conversion either, it throws the same error.

Edit: The end goal is something like `discordpp::ApplicationCommandOption option{.type = 3, .name = "message", .description = "The message to echo", .required = true};` where all of those parameters are differently-typed fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that two class-type conversions are required:

- `const char[6]` to `std::string`
- `std::string` to `field<std::string>`.

There is a rule that implicit conversion can have at most one class-type conversion (the official term is "user-defined" conversion although this includes class types that are part of the standard library).

To fix it you can either use your suggested fix; or manually specify one of the conversions, e.g:

```
auto strB = field<std::string>("Hello");
field<std::string> strC = std::string("Hello");
field<std::string> strD = "Hello"s;
```

or you could add a constructor for `const char[]`.

SFINAE version of char array constructor (there will be better ways in C++20 I'm sure):

```
template<size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>>>
field(char const (&t)[N])
    : t_(std::make_unique<T>(t)) {}
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a constructor for `const char[]` for only `field<std::string>`? Not a great solution but it works.

Comment: @Aido yes - have the `const char[]` constructor and include a SFINAE or Concept to only enable it when T equals `std::string`.

Comment: What would the syntax for those be? I'm reading the pages on cppreference but I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: Hmm, I maybe need to update for concepts but would `field(const std::convertible_to<T> &ctt) : t_(std::make_unique<T>(t)) {}` theoretically work?

Comment: @Aido Lots of possible solutions no doubt, I've added a SFINAE one now

Comment: Oh wait that starts to complain if I declare `field<int> i = 1;` because `error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration`

Comment: It works as `template<size_t N>  field(char const (&t)[N]) requires std::is_same_v<T, std::string>  : t_(std::make_unique<T>(t)) {}` but I believe that requires C++20

Comment: Ooh `template<typename F> field(const F& f) requires std::convertible_to<F, T> : t_(std::make_unique<T>(f)) {}` works